# Image not centering in bootstrap

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

Having tried the solutions suggested in the other posts, I'm left to post my novice code in which the embedded image simply will not centre and I haven't a clue why. The image should appear in the middle of a login screen/box; it did for the guy who did the demo, yet I've had to alter his CSS to make it marginally better. Still, the image will not centre. Does anyone have any insight?

**HTML**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>

<html lang="en">
    <head>
        <!-- Standard Meta Tags -->

        <!-- Bootstrap & Related Links-->

        <link rel="stylesheet" href="static/styles.css">

        <title>Project</title>
    </head>
    <body>
        <!-- cont is the entire box; changing its CSS changes its position on the page -->
        <div class="cont">
            <!-- box is the area that contains the image, username, and pass fields, but not the button bar and login buttons -->
            <div class="box">
                <!-- Creates the entire top row with close button and three circular buttons
                <div class="row top">
                    <div class="left">
                        <i class="fa fa-times close"></i>
                    </div>
                    <div class="right">
                        <i class=" fa fa-circle but one"></i>
                        <i class=" fa fa-circle but two"></i>
                        <i class=" fa fa-circle but three"></i>
                    </div>
                </div>
                -->
                <div class="row middle sg">
                    <div class="row pic sg">
                        <div class="col-md-4 col-md-offset-4">
                            <img src="static/fleur.jpeg" alt="fleur-de-lis" class="photo">
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <form action="#" class="form-horizontal form">
                        <div class="input-group y">
                            <span class="input-group-addon"><i class="fa fa-user use"></i></span>
                            <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Username">
                        </div>
                        <div class="input-group">
                            <span class="input-group-addon"><i class="fa faunlock-alt use"></i></span>
                            <input type="password" class="form-control" placeholder="Password">
                        </div>
                    </form>
                </div>
                <div class="row base sg">
                    <h2 class="text-center login">Login</h2>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

**CSS**

```
html, body {
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
}

.cont {
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    display: flex;
    align-items: center;
    justify-content: center;
}

.box {
    background-color: #2B2B35;
    width: 400px;
    border-radius: 10px;
}

.top {
    width: 100%;
    background-color: #24242E;
    margin: 0;
    border-radius: 10px 10px 0 0;
    padding: 0 15px;
}

.left {
    float: left;
}

.right {
    float: right;
}

.close {
    padding: 18px 0;
    font-size: 20px;
    color: #fff;
}

.but {
    padding: 18px 0 18px 5px;
    font-size: 20px;
}

.but:hover {
    cursor: pointer;
}

.one {
    color: #F4CB61;
}

.two {
    color: #DB5594;
}

.three {
    color: #6451E8;
}

.photo {
    width: 200px;
    border-radius: 50%;

}

.sg {
    display: block;
    margin-left: auto;
    margin-right: auto;
    align-items: center;
    justify-content: center;

}

.pic {
    margin: 40px 0 30px 0;
}

.form {
    padding: 0 40px 40px 40px;
}

.login {
    padding: 12px 0;
    margin: 0;
}

.base {
    background-color: #3FA752;
    border-radius: 0 0 10px 10px;
    color: #fff;
}

.base:hover {
    cursor: pointer;
}

.base h2{
    font-weight: 600;
    font-size: 26px;
}

.user {
    color: #ccc;
}

.y {
    padding-bottom: 15px;
}

input[type=text],
input[type=password] {
    background: 0, 0;
    border: 0;
    box-shadow: none;
    border-radius: 0;
    border-bottom: 1px solid #9446B6;
}

.input-group-addon {
    background: 0 0;
    border: 0;
    border-radius: 0;
    border-bottom: 1px solid #9AA6B6;
}

.use {
    color: #9AA6B6;
}

input[type=text],
input[type=password]:focus{
    box-shadow: none !important;
    color: #FF3F3F;

}
```

Comment: I cant see a link to the bootstrap stylesheet? Have you got that somewhere?

Comment: Yes, all standard boostrap links are in the file. Just omitted here for brevity.

Comment: I've updated my answer with a possible fix, take a look.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Updated:

Removing these classes `class="col-md-4 col-md-offset-4"` and adding a class to center the image fixes the problem.

```css
html, body {
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
}

.cont {
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    display: flex;
    align-items: center;
    justify-content: center;
}

.box {
    background-color: #2B2B35;
    width: 400px;
    border-radius: 10px;
}

.top {
    width: 100%;
    background-color: #24242E;
    margin: 0;
    border-radius: 10px 10px 0 0;
    padding: 0 15px;
}

.left {
    float: left;
}

.right {
    float: right;
}

.close {
    padding: 18px 0;
    font-size: 20px;
    color: #fff;
}

.but {
    padding: 18px 0 18px 5px;
    font-size: 20px;
}

.but:hover {
    cursor: pointer;
}

.one {
    color: #F4CB61;
}

.two {
    color: #DB5594;
}

.three {
    color: #6451E8;
}
.text-center {
  text-align: center;
}
.photo {
    width: 200px;
    border-radius: 50%;
    
}

.sg {
    display: block;
    margin-left: auto;
    margin-right: auto;
    align-items: center;
    justify-content: center;

}

.pic {
    margin: 40px 0 30px 0;
}

.form {
    padding: 0 40px 40px 40px;
}

.login {
    padding: 12px 0;
    margin: 0;
}

.base {
    background-color: #3FA752;
    border-radius: 0 0 10px 10px;
    color: #fff;
}

.base:hover {
    cursor: pointer;
}

.base h2{
    font-weight: 600;
    font-size: 26px;
}

.user {
    color: #ccc;
}

.y {
    padding-bottom: 15px;
}

input[type=text],
input[type=password] {
    background: 0, 0;
    border: 0;
    box-shadow: none;
    border-radius: 0;
    border-bottom: 1px solid #9446B6;
}

.input-group-addon {
    background: 0 0;
    border: 0;
    border-radius: 0;
    border-bottom: 1px solid #9AA6B6;
}

.use {
    color: #9AA6B6;
}

input[type=text],
input[type=password]:focus{
    box-shadow: none !important;
    color: #FF3F3F;

}
```

```html
<html lang="en">
    <head>
        <!-- Standard Meta Tags -->
<!-- Latest compiled and minified CSS -->
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-BVYiiSIFeK1dGmJRAkycuHAHRg32OmUcww7on3RYdg4Va+PmSTsz/K68vbdEjh4u" crossorigin="anonymous">
        <!-- Bootstrap & Related Links-->

        <link rel="stylesheet" href="static/styles.css">

        <title>Project</title>
    </head>
    <body>
        <!-- cont is the entire box; changing its CSS changes its position on the page -->
        <div class="cont">
            <!-- box is the area that contains the image, username, and pass fields, but not the button bar and login buttons -->
            <div class="box">
                <!-- Creates the entire top row with close button and three circular buttons
                <div class="row top">
                    <div class="left">
                        <i class="fa fa-times close"></i>
                    </div>
                    <div class="right">
                        <i class=" fa fa-circle but one"></i>
                        <i class=" fa fa-circle but two"></i>
                        <i class=" fa fa-circle but three"></i>
                    </div>
                </div>
                -->
                <div class="row middle sg">
                    <div class="row pic sg">
                        <div class="text-center">
                            <img src="https://placeimg.com/200/200/nature" alt="fleur-de-lis" class="photo">
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <form action="#" class="form-horizontal form">
                        <div class="input-group y">
                            <span class="input-group-addon"><i class="fa fa-user use"></i></span>
                            <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Username">
                        </div>
                        <div class="input-group">
                            <span class="input-group-addon"><i class="fa faunlock-alt use"></i></span>
                            <input type="password" class="form-control" placeholder="Password">
                        </div>
                    </form>
                </div>
                <div class="row base sg">
                    <h2 class="text-center login">Login</h2>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

By default images are `inline-block` elements, they follow the regular flow and should be centered with `text-align` (set in the parent).

Images can be set to `display` as `block` elements, to center these the value of width must be set (amount, percent,...), and both **left and right margins set to auto**.

```css
.container {
  width: 100%;
}

.tex-center {
  text-align: center;
}

#inline-example {
  display: inline-block; /* Default value*/
}

#block-example {
  display: block;
  max-width: 200px;
  margin: 0 auto 0 auto;
}
```

```html
<h3>Inline centered image</h3>
<div class="container tex-center"><img id="inline-example" src="https://placeimg.com/200/200/nature"></div>
<h3>Block centered image</h3>
<div class="container"><img id="block-example" src="https://placeimg.com/200/200/people"></div>
```

How to find out similar CSS issues. Using Chrome's devtools (or similar) we can see there's a margin in the left pushing the image. `col-md-4 col-md-offset-4` are both Bootsrap classes used for a grid setup, trying and removing them gives us the solution.

[image: Detail of the problem]

Comment: Sure, I updated the answer with a little explanation that can help you in the future.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
.photo {
    width: 200px;
    border-radius: 50%;
    display: block;
    margin: auto;
}
```

To center an image in a div, you should normally set the `display` to `block` and `margin` to `auto` on the `img`.

Comment: Sadly, no change. The most profound, positive change I got was changing the .sg rules.

Answer (score 0):

If you are talking about this image `<img src="static/fleur.jpeg" alt="fleur-de-lis" class="photo">` then you should add to your 'photo' class:

```
display:block;
margin: 0 auto;
```

Make sure other CSS wont prevent those lines to work and your image should centre itself within your col-element.

Answer (score 0):

Your image is in column with offset, remove column classes (event whole div) and all will work well with:

```
.photo {
    display: block; // defining element as block
    margin: 0 auto; // and auto side margin
    width: 200px;
    border-radius: 50%;
}
```

Example:
https://codepen.io/themeler/pen/QqNpWv